# I need help converting a c# anonymous method to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, silverlight

```
provider.OptionsSet += delegate
{
  provider.FinishedLoading();
};
```

Answer (score 4):

Nice demonstration how converters get this dramatically wrong, they have for a long time.  The += operator isn't VB.NET syntax, AddHandler is required to subscribe events.  Where the *Do* comes from is anybody's guess.  The lambda can't be a Function, except for the very rare cases where the delegate type returns a value.  Three bugs in one line, you don't stand a chance.  You need VS2010 to write a Sub lambda.  Like this:

```
Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim obj As New Test
        AddHandler obj.example, Sub(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
                                    '' etc...
                                End Sub
    End Sub
End Module

Class Test
    Public Event example As EventHandler
End Class
```

For earlier versions, you'll need a little non-anonymous helper method.  Like this:

```
    AddHandler obj.example, AddressOf helper
...
Sub helper(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    '' etc..
End Sub
```

Human 1, machine 0.

Comment: Thanks, Hans, that should do it.  I had already tried varuiys code converter's and done a little research on lamda's etc. with no success.  Interestingly, even what Reflector said it should be was wrong.  Something like your first answer only it generated Function/End Function (inline) and VS2010 didn't like it.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Pete Brown has also has an example with inline sub:

http://10rem.net/blog/2010/04/16/tip-anonymous-event-handlers-in-vbnet

Answer (score -2):

```
provider.OptionsSet += Function() Do
    provider.FinishedLoading() 
End Function
```

This is taken from http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/, so I haven't tested it. It might be more helpful if you were able to provide more context. What is this being used for?