# help to convert c# anonymous to vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net

Please help me to convert this below code to vb.net. I have no idea to convert from anonymous method to vb.net. I'm currently using VS2010.

```
    public void DoWork(CustomObject obj)
    {
        var linq = (from s in storages
                     where s.Key == obj.Key
                     select s.Value).ToList();

        Action<ICustomService> act =
            delegate(ICustomService service)
            {
                service.ChangeValue(obj);
            };

        linq.ForEach(act);
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Pure C# Developer

Comment: VB.NET anonymous types are just `Dim somename = ...`

Comment: Why aren't you using a normal `foreach` statement?

Comment: @BoltClock: He said anonymous method (delegate), not anonymous type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need help converting a c# anonymous method to vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279477/i-need-help-converting-a-c-anonymous-method-to-vb-net)

Comment: @Meta-Knight; Follow your code. it works now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Public Sub DoWork(ByVal obj As CustomObject)

    Dim values = (From s In storages
                 Where s.Key = obj.Key
                 Select s.Value).ToList()

    values.ForEach(Sub(service As ICustomService) service.ChangeValue(obj))

End Sub
```

Comment: vcha did mention he used VS2010 ;-)

Comment: Great, you beat the other horrid answers by a mile. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try using this online c# to vb.net code conversion:

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: Don't bother trying it for this question. If you feed it anonymous functions, it produces code that doesn't compile :(

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Sub DoWork(ByVal obj As CustomObject)
    Dim linq = storage.Where(Function(s) s.Key = obj.Key).[Select](Function(s) s.Value).ToList()

    Dim act As Action(Of ICustomService) = Sub(service As ICustomService)
                                               service.ChangeValue(obj)
                                           End Sub

    linq.ForEach(act)
End Sub
```

Comment: @Bala R; Thank you for yr fast reply. I also would like to ask that the code "(from s in storages where s.Key == select s.Value).ToList();" can be used in VB.NET or not? I'm just curious on it.

Comment: There is no such thing as Function() Do in VB. it should just be Sub(). Also, brackets around Select aren't necessary...

Comment: Look at my answer! I didn't use a translator, my code actually works ;-)

Comment: @vcha you can from the query syntax `(from s in storage...)` but VB.Net syntax is slightly different see Meta-Knight's answer.

Comment: @ downvoter care to give a reason? I verified that this edited snippet compiles! @Hans , perhaps?

Comment: @Bala R; Thank you for your try anyway.

Answer (score -1):

[SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Default.aspx) is a free IDE for dotnet that supports several **automatic sourcecode translations** i.e. C# to VB.NET, IronRuby or IronPyton

For your example it produced

```
'
' * Created by SharpDevelop.
' * User: k3b
' * Date: 26.03.2011
' * Time: 18:44
' * 
' * To change this template use Tools | Options | Coding | Edit Standard Headers.
' 

Imports System

Namespace DefaultNamespace
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Description of Class1.
    ''' </summary>
    Public Class Class1
        Public Sub New()
        End Sub
        Public Sub DoWork(obj As CustomObject)
            Dim linq = (From s In storages Where s.Key = obj.Keys.Value).ToList()

            Dim act As Action(Of ICustomService) = Function(service As ICustomService) Do
                service.ChangeValue(obj)
            End Function

            linq.ForEach(act)
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace
```

Comment: @k3b; Thank you so much. I will use this site to translate the simple C# code. I think it should be ok on that but is there any reliable on-line converter?

Comment: Yay for translators, but in this case the code just doesn't compile. It should be Sub instead of Function..do. You guys should at least make sure that the code compiles!

Comment: @Hans Passant: sorry i pasted only part of the generated code. Fixed my source

Comment: I posted a bugreport to the sharpdevelop-team. Sorry for wrong answer :-(