# How to use DispatcherOperationCallback in vb.net

Tags: c#, wpf, vb.net, xbap

I have a problem with coverting c# to vb.net on using DispatcherOperationCallback.

I have tried to convert it based on [help to convert c# anonymous to vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443950/help-to-convert-c-anonymous-to-vb-net)

I'm using VS2010.

I have a c# code like this:

```
    public void Callback(Contract contract)
    {
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
              (DispatcherOperationCallback)delegate(object arg)
              {
                  Contract obj = (Contract)arg;
                  txtRequest.Text = HandleArgument(obj);                      
                  return null;
              }, contract);
    }
```

And After I tried to change to vb.net like this

```
Public Sub Callback(ByVal contract As Contract) Implements IServiceCallback.Callback

    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(New DispatcherOperationCallback(Sub(arg As Object)
                                                           txtRequest.Text = HandleArgument(DirectCast(arg, Contract))
                                                           End Sub), DispatcherPriority.Normal, contract)

End Sub
```

but it did not work. The vs2010 displayed "nested sub does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate "Delegate Function DispatcherOperationCallback(arg As Object) As Object"

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just read the error message:

```
nested sub does not have a signature that is compatible with delegate 
  "Delegate Function DispatcherOperationCallback(arg As Object) As Object
```

so, you should change you code accordingly.

```
Public Sub Callback(ByVal contract As Contract) Implements IServiceCallback.Callback
    Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
      New DispatcherOperationCallback(
          Function(arg As Object)
              txtRequest.Text = HandleArgument(DirectCast(arg, Contract))
              Return Nothing ' // you need to check what should be returned here '
          End Function), 
         DispatcherPriority.Normal, 
         contract)
End Sub
```

Comment: In fact, I do not need to return anything. I just want to pass arg to HandleArgument function to perform some task and return string back to TextBox named txtRequest. That's all.

Comment: That may be true, but the `DispatcherOperationCallback` expects a function, not a method.