# C# to VB: Class.Event += (sender, args) => FunctionName(params)

Tags: c#, vb.net, event-handling, c#-to-vb.net

I'm trying to convert the C# code from [this webpage](http://gallery.expression.microsoft.com/BusyIndicator) to VB.

Everything seems to have converted pretty much fine using an online converter tool, but then I reach the following line:

```
fadeOutAnimation.Completed += (sender, args) => OnFadeOutAnimationCompleted(d, hostGrid, grid);
```

The fadeOutAnimation.Completed event produces an event with the signature (sender, args), and d, hostGrid and grid are variables local to the function containing this mysterious event handler assignment.

I think I can see that the instruction on this C# line is telling the code to execute the OnFadeOutAnimationCompleted function, using d, hostgrid and grid as parameters, when fadeoutAnimation.Completed occurs, but I have no idea what to even search for in order to replicate this behaviour in VB.net.

Can someone provide me with some terminology so I can better educate myself on whatever this is called?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I need help converting a c# anonymous method to vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279477/i-need-help-converting-a-c-anonymous-method-to-vb-net)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
AddHandler fadeOutAnimation.Completed, Sub() 
    OnFadeOutAnimationCompleted(d, hostGrid, grid)
End Sub
```

It's been a while, but since you're not using the parameters in the Event Handler I don't think you need to include them (because of Relaxed Delegate Conversion). If so, it'll look more like:

```
AddHandler fadeOutAnimation.Completed, Sub(sender as object, args as EventArgs) 
    OnFadeOutAnimationCompleted(d, hostGrid, grid)
End Sub
```

Comment: +1 Worth mentioning that Visual Studio 2010 is required to use an anonymous `Sub` in VB (either syntax)

Answer (score 1):

This is a lambda expression. Let me see how to do this in VB...

```
AddHandler fadeOutAnimation.Completed, Sub(sender, e) _
(OnFadeOutAnimationCompleted(d, hostGrid, grid))
```

Answer (score 1):

They keywork you have to look for is "lambda expression".