# Filestream from Twitter, can't understand the C# (VB.NET needed really)

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I'm trying to use an twitter API and I have limited C# knowledge (=/)

Could someone explain to me what exactly is the code above, and how it would be in VB.Net?

```
var filteredStream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
filteredStream.AddTrack("ladygaga");
filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) => { Console.WriteLine(args.Tweet.Text); };
filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
```

I appreciate the help, thx

Comment: you do know there are free online converters, right?  http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: I would like to understand what is going on there =/

Comment: theoretically, if you know VB and convert it to VB you'll understand what it does, no?  the **only** tricky thing is that the "+=" there is adding an event handler.

Comment: Actually the code seems little strange when converted, the "filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) => " part...

Comment: That's just "AddHandler filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived, Sub(sender, args) Console.WriteLine(args.Tweet.Text)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim filteredStream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream()
filteredStream.AddTrack("ladygaga")
AddHandler filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived, Sub(sender as object, args as EventArgs) 
    Console.WriteLine(args.Tweet.Text);
End Sub
filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions()
```

The code creates a `FilteredStream` variable and adds the track `"ladygaga"` to it, it registers an event handler that prints the tweet text when a tweet containing that text is posted.

For the line you were having trouble on, check [VB AddHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5566702/1218281).