# C# code to VB.net equivalent

Tags: c#, vb.net

What is the equivalent of following C# code to VB.net code.

```
public void RaiseTotalTimeEvent(TotalTimeEventArgs e)
        {
            EventHandler<TotalTimeEventArgs> temp = TotalTimeEvent;
            if (temp != null)
            {
                temp(this, e);
            }
        }
```

**EDIT**
Thanks for the answer.

But all the answers looks like it was converted using some of the existing CODE converter.
I have tried [Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/),[DeveloperFusion](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/), And others. All these tools generate same code like below and none of these work.
Converted Code.

```
Public Sub RaiseTotalTimeEvent(e As TotalTimeEventArgs)
    Dim temp As EventHandler(Of TotalTimeEventArgs) = TotalTimeEvent
    RaiseEvent temp(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Compiler Reports with this error:

> Error 8   'Public Event CountEvent(sender As Object, e As
>   CountEventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a
>   'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

Comment: Try this - http://converter.telerik.com/

Comment: The Event keyword works differently in VB.NET.  No need for the null check, just use RaiseEvent TotalTimeEvent(Me, e)

Comment: @Hans has posted the correct answer. It's a pity this question was closed, it seems a perfectly good question to me. Especially since the online converters **sometimes produce code that doesn't compile** [Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279477/i-need-help-converting-a-c-anonymous-method-to-vb-net/5280092#5280092)

Comment: Simply awful that a question like this was closed - instead of pulling some moral highground, someone could have taken the opportunity to actually teach and share their knowledge - but maybe SO is more about cursing at others instead of helping. If anyone ever needs to simply know what something is in a foreign language, I would highly recommend they spend years studying in a university classroom instead of using Google Translate or asking someone for a little help. God forbid they actually ask a question on a site designed to be helpful. Ugh...really?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid automatically translating code from one language into another. Instead you should learn to understand and rewrite the code to solve the problem in your preferred language.

But there are translators. http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Comment: But the translators sometimes produce code that does not compile... for instance OP complains they produce invalid code for this question. [Another example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279477/i-need-help-converting-a-c-anonymous-method-to-vb-net/5280092#5280092)

Comment: Code Translators are always the worst solution for translating code!! Reading someone others code and re-implementing it is fine. Think first than write code! #ThinkFirstDevelopment

Comment: I'd have thought it is acceptable to use a converter to do the "grunt work" of conversion - changing void to Sub, replacing curly braces etc, as long as you sanity check the output afterwards, particularly any part that might be controversial.

Answer (score 1):

I think it will look like this.

```
Public Sub RaiseTotalTimeEvent(e As TotalTimeEventArgs)
    Dim temp As EventHandler(Of TotalTimeEventArgs) = TotalTimeEvent
    RaiseEvent temp(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Comment: OP says this does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

You could have easily done it by using some on-line C# to VB conversion tool. Anyway below is the equivalent VB code.

```
Public Sub RaiseTotalTimeEvent(e As TotalTimeEventArgs)
    Dim temp As EventHandler(Of TotalTimeEventArgs) = TotalTimeEvent
    RaiseEvent temp(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Comment: OP says this does not compile. Those online tools do sometimes produce invalid code.

Answer (score 0):

Look here for an autoconverter: http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

```
Public Sub RaiseTotalTimeEvent(e As TotalTimeEventArgs)
    Dim temp As EventHandler(Of TotalTimeEventArgs) = TotalTimeEvent
    RaiseEvent temp(Me, e)
End Sub
```

Misses the if, but that should be simple.

Comment: OP says this does not compile